# todo list- trying to add inputs to an array/doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a small todo list and want to do the following: each text input (or actually a copy of the text input) should be added to an empty string (copy because it should not disappear when added). Then I have a function which is called when user clicks on a button and then I want to pick a random todo thing.
I didn't even get to the point when I pick out a random todo thing because my code just doesn't work- It seems like the adding does happen, but instead of adding a todo thing, thats being added:`[object HTMLInputElement]`
Anyone has an idea?

My javascript code:

```
var totalItems=0;
var listOf="";
function randomItem(){
    document.getElementById("randomArray").innerHTML=listOf;
}

function updatingItem() {

    var cbId = this.id.replace("cb_", "");
    var textItem = document.getElementById("item_" + cbId);
    if (this.checked) {
        textItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
        textItem.style.background="pink";
    }
    else {
        textItem.style.textDecoration = "none";
        textItem.style.background="white";
    }
}
function addItem() {
    totalItems++;

    var entry = document.createElement("li");
    var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
    checkBox.type = "checkbox";
    checkBox.id = "cb_" + totalItems;
    checkBox.onclick = updatingItem;

    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.id = "item_" + totalItems;
    span.innerHtml = textItem;

    var textItem = document.getElementById("textItem");
    span.innerText = textItem.value;

    var location = document.getElementById("todoList");

    entry.appendChild(checkBox);
    entry.appendChild(span);
    location.appendChild(entry);
    var listOfItems=textItem;
    listOf+=listOfItems;
}

var item = document.getElementById("add");
item.onclick = addItem;
document.getElementById("lastButton").onclick=randomItem;
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="table">
        <h1>To Do List</h1>
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="text" id="textItem"/>
        <button id="add"><b>Add</b></button>
    </p>
    <ul id="todoList"></ul>
    <h3>Pick a random to do thing to do for today</h3>
    <button id="lastButton">Go!</button>
    <p id="randomArray"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: there's a couple of errors:
1) checkBox.onclick = updatingItem; shoud be: checkBox.onclick = "updatingItem()"; The same for item.onclick = addItem;.
2) The updatingItem variable is private in updatingItem function, and you're trying to read it in addItem function.
Try to fix this.

Comment: actually I did this on purpose because item.onclick = addItem(); is wrong- if I do that, the function is being called right away, thats not what I want. Also, i´the entire code works just fine so I shouldn't be changing the things you mentioned, only the part where im trying to add the inputs to the array doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your `randomItem()` function is working incorrectly, as you are trying to create `String` from `Object` directly while using `listOfItems`. Either use its value or try using following code instead for proper view. Also add one list element in HTML with `id="myList"`. IT will work fine.

JS:

```
function randomItem(){
    var counter = 0;
    var textItems = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var done = [];

    for (var i=0; i<textItems.length; i++)
    {
        if(textItems[i].type == "checkbox")
        {
            if(textItems[i].checked)
            {
                document.getElementById("item_"+i);

                done.push(document.getElementById("item_"+i).innerHTML);

                var list = document.getElementById('myList');

                var data = document.createElement('li');
                data.appendChild(document.createTextNode(done[counter]));
                counter++;
                list.appendChild(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<ol id = "myList"></ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var listOfItems=textItem.value;
```

rather than

```
var listOfItems=textItem;
```

Comment: It all works great now, just that when I changed my code and only wanted to only add those input items into the array that were not checked off, it stopped working..